# Transfer matrix for Potts models

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

The interaction energy for Potts model (on an dicrete interval with periodic boundary condition, i.e. a $\mathbb{Z}_N$- model) is of the form
$$E(\{\sigma\})=-\sum\limits_{\langle n,m\rangle} \delta_{\sigma_n,\sigma_m},$$
with $\sigma_n=\pm 1$. In one place I found an information that the transfer matrix for such a model is given by 
$$\langle \sigma| T |\sigma'\rangle=e^{\beta(\delta_{\sigma,\sigma'}+1)}.$$
Why it is so? I do not understand the origin of this "$+1$". I looks like some kind of "self-interaction" was included there, but why?

Comment: I don't see any reason whatsoever to do so (where did you read this?). But in any case, this does not change anything (it will just shift the free energy by a constant).

Comment: (Note also that the added term is not a self-interaction, as it affects in the same way all elements of the transfer matrix; a self-interaction term would only affect the diagonal.)